# Create multiple records for each record in a table by combining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first post so I apologize for not knowing how to format this properly.

I have two tables (Table A and B). Table A has 1 column and 10 records and Table B has 1 column and 5 records. How do I combine them so that the end result is one table with two columns and 50 records?

To put this in other words, for each record in Table A, I want to create 5 records corresponding to the different values in Table B.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF38w.png)

Comment: Hint:  `CROSS JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2
FROM TableA a
CROSS JOIN TableB b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like **Cross join**. This might be helpful https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php